# How to get build status when using the maven invoker?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I'm developing a plugin that verifies if a maven project compiles or not, I'm using the maven invoker to run `install` goal on each project but I didn't find how to get the build result from, here's an example of the code I'm trying to use:

```
private void verify(File file) {
    Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
    InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
    request.setGoals(Collections.singletonList("install"))
    .setMavenOpts("-Dmaven.test.skip=true")
    .setBaseDirectory(file).
    setBatchMode(true);
    try {
        invoker.execute(request);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        failedToCompileList.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        getLog().error(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Usage page](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/usage.html), you just need to check the results of the `execute` statement:

```
InvocationResult result = invoker.execute( request );
 
if ( result.getExitCode() != 0 )
{
    throw new IllegalStateException( "Build failed." );
}
```

> This will retrieve the exit code from the invocation result, and throw an exception if it's not 0 (the traditional all-clear code). Note that we could capture the build output by adding an InvocationOutputHandler instance to either the invoker or the request.

Adding this to your example would be:

```
private void verify(File file) {
    Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
    InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
    request.setGoals(Collections.singletonList("install"))
    .setMavenOpts("-Dmaven.test.skip=true")
    .setBaseDirectory(file).
    setBatchMode(true);
    try {
        InvocationResult result = invoker.execute(request);
        if ( result.getExitCode() != 0 )
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException( "Build failed." );
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        failedToCompileList.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        getLog().error(e);
    }
}
```